# Value of timezone gets added in the selected time (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I'm using current user time to show time. But the timezone of user gets added in the time selected. Let's say, if user's timezone is `+05:30 Asia/Kolkata` ,then the value `05:30` gets added in the selected time. This is the code I'm using.

```
def customer_timezone
      user_profile_timezone = current_user.user_profile.timezone_name
        if user_profile_timezone.present?
          time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[user_profile_timezone]
          @user_timezone = "#{time_zone.formatted_offset} - #{time_zone.name}" if time_zone.present?
        end
        return @user_timezone
    end
```

Is there any way possible to resolve this issue?

Comment: could you please add more details about how you have used `customer_timezone` in the app?

Comment: I've used `customer_timezone` only for displaying the timezone in customer profile.

Comment: Hey, can you please update your question please? What is the exact requirement? What is the method `formatted_offset`?